# Primefaces Pie Chart using Oracle Database Data

Tags: java, oracle, jsf-2, pie-chart

I am using primefaces for the first time and I am Able to display pie Chart using hard coded figures Like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Stanley
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "chartBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {

    private PieChartModel pieModel;

    public ChartBean() {
        createPieModel();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
        return pieModel;
    }

    private void createPieModel() {
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();
        pieModel.set("Branch1", 540);
        pieModel.set("Branch2", 325);
        pieModel.set("Branch3", 702);
        //Feed these values from the database dynamically
    }

}
```

I have a query for extracting the same information from the database dynamically for all the Branches like this:

```
select branch_code, count(*) accounts_opened from account_master where acct_opn_date
>= trunc(sysdate,'mm')
group by branch_code;
```

My question is how can I be able to display the same Information on this Pie Chart using My values from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values from oracle and set values from Resulset.

Like this

```
Connection con = YOUR_CONNECTION;
PreparedStatment ps = con.prepareStatment(YOU SELECT);

ResultSet  result = ps.executeQuery();
while (result.next())
{
  pieModel.set(result.getSting("branch_code"), result.gtInt("accounts_opened "));
}
```